# Is there a way that WCF service can know which machine the call comes from?

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

I have a WCF service and without changing any code on the client side, is there a way that I can know the detail information of the caller, such as the MachineName, and ApplicationName?

Basically, I cannot change the client code to pass those pieces of information over.

I tried to use System.Web.HttpContext on the server side to track this information, but HttpContext.Current is NULL. I guess that is not the proper usage of it.

Any suggestion?

Thanks
Sarah

Comment: I know you say you can't change the client code, but if the service is supposed to report on which clients are using the service then the contract should specify a clientId / userId / sourceId - it's the preferred solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer through this article: [Client IP addresses in Orcas](http://blogs.msdn.com/phenning/archive/2007/08/08/remoteendpointmessageproperty-in-wcf-net-3-5.aspx).

And here is a snippet of the code (with .NET 3.5):

```
// Track the IP address and port of the calling client
OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current;
MessageProperties properties = context.IncomingMessageProperties;
RemoteEndpointMessageProperty endpoint = properties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
Trace.TraceInformation("Receive a document from {0}:{1} via {2}", endpoint.Address, endpoint.Port, properties.Via.AbsoluteUri);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the IP address in WCF 3.5, but that's it (setting aside duplex services during which you may get a return URL)